# Is there a Wordpress plugin to serve cached content to the public during maintenance?

Tags: wordpress, caching, maintenance

I know there's [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) and [WP Maintenance Mode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/), but I don't want to show a "The website is under maintenance" warning. I want something like this:

- Click a button "start maintenance". This should cache the entire website and serve it to signed out users while admins can test, create posts, change colors, etc without worrying about their changes being visible to the public.
- When maintenance is over, I click "done" and that invalidates the cache, showing the new content to the public.

Is there any such thing or am I out of luck?

Comment: A "caching proxy" put in front of your WP might be able to do that (just as a hint – I've never setup such a thing, so I cannot put it into an answer).